# Error CS0411 en @Html.LabelFor - The type arguments for method .. cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Hola que tal estoy intentando crear el formulario para insertar datos y estaba utilizando un HtmlHelper, me marca un error pero no logro encontrar la razón.

El error que me lanza dice:

> CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'LabelExtensions.LabelFor(HtmlHelper,
>   Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Y mi codigo llevo esto:

```
@model List<Shoes.Models.ViewModels.ListProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nuevo";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Nuevo", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Id, " ", new { @class = "form-control"})

    </div>



</div>
}
```

los errores me marcan en el `LabelFor` y `TextboxFor`

Si necesitan algún otro detalle, estoy a sus ordenes, saludos

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta, e indica también el Modelo `ListProductsViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio, veo que tienes un **error de compatibilidad** entre el Modelo que recibe la Vista, y la asignación que estas haciendo a los **HtmHelpers** `@Html.LabelFor` y `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

Estás recibiendo una Lista `List<Shoes.Models.ViewModels.ListProductsViewModel>`. Y luego intentas asignar a los **HtmlHelpers** una propiedad individual: `@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Id)`.

**Primera alternativa:**

Cambia el Modelo de datos que recibe la vista a un **objeto individual**:

```
@model Shoes.Models.ViewModels.ListProductsViewModel
```

**Segunda alternativa:**

Si **realmente lo que quieres recibir** en la Vista es una **Lista de objetos** `@model List<Shoes.Models.ViewModels.ListProductsViewModel>`, Debes "iterar" en los elementos (`foreach`) de esta, para formar un Form de **múltiples entradas**:

```
@model List<Shoes.Models.ViewModels.ListProductsViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Nuevo", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(d => item.id)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(d => item.id, " ", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```